# run a program in seconds rather than milliseconds

Tags: javascript, performance, javascript-framework

I have a home made(not by me of course) program that runs in milliseconds and I'd literally have to put millions of milliseconds to get it to do what I want it to do, so I'm trying to change it to seconds, or even minutes... I know the var milli is what I should be changing but dunno if I change it to var sec or var secs or var seconds or what, I'm not very knowledgeable of coding so I'm sure this is a simple answer, and I've tried a few different things that did not work, so that's why I came here, thanks if you can answer :) ignore the fact that it's not properly formatted as code in this post

```
<script>
    var a=0;
var milli;
    function collect1()
    {
        var milli = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
        var links=document.getElementById('linkholder').value;
        links = links.replace(/[\n\r]/gi , " ");
        var link=links.split(" ",100000);
        var iframe1=document.getElementById('iframe1');
        iframe1.onload = function(){setTimeout(collect1, milli);};
        iframe1.src=link[a];
        a++;
```

Comment: Dude, the code is incomplete

Comment: You really couldn't figure out how to mulitple with 1000, and then with 60 to get minutes etc ?

Comment: check out the program, sure I can multiply, but I'm trying to simplify it, have it run in seconds rather than milliseconds, or possibly have another version of the program to run in minutes http://prntscr.com/2z4s8c

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
var milli = document.getElementById("numbers").value;
```

to

```
var milli = document.getElementById("numbers").value * 1000;
```

1 second is 1000 milliseconds.

Also note that this variable `milli` is not the same as the `var milli;` on the third line. If you want to turn that variable into seconds you need to multiply it with 1000 too.

Comment: and change it to var milli = document.getElementById("numbers").value * 60000;  if I want it to run in minutes?  this may help you understan more of what I'm trying to do http://prntscr.com/2z4s8c

Comment: @user3397097 Yes, exactly. This should be all you need to accomplish that.

Comment: Yeah, really, thanks, I was able to do one for seconds by adding in the * 1000, one for minutes by adding in  * 60000 and one for hours by adding in * 3600000

Answer (score 0):

1 sec = 1000 milliseconds

The only place you are using the `milli` variable in the code you've provided is here:

```
iframe1.onload = function(){setTimeout(collect1, milli);};
```

so if you want the whatever the milli variable is to actually be how many seconds you want to wait then multiply it by 1000:

```
iframe1.onload = function(){setTimeout(collect1, milli*1000);};
```

Side note: That is going to wait a long time....

Comment: that makes sense, so if I wanted to make the program run in minutes, I'd change it to  (collect1, milli*60000);};   ???

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to guess, what your code is meant for, since I don't know what your html page looks like.

But since the variable `milli` is only used once (as a parameter to `setTimeout`), I would guess that you could change that line of code from:

```
    iframe1.onload = function(){setTimeout(collect1, milli);};
```

to:

```
    iframe1.onload = function(){setTimeout(collect1, milli * 1000);};
```

and see what is happening.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2z4s8c this may explain what I'm trying to do a little better... rather than use milliseconds, I'd rather use seconds, or minutes

Comment: In this case I would suggest to use @pstenstrm's solution.